# Asynchronous Execution Issue with Reactive Programming in Java

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a method (enrichData) that retrieves metadata for an ID from different sources (LocalCache, RedisCache, and ApiService) using Project Reactor's Mono in Java. The goal is to ensure that only one API call is made, and subsequent calls should fetch data from the local cache.

I've tried using subscribeOn(Schedulers.single()) to handle concurrency, but it seems that multiple API calls are still being made concurrently. How can I modify the code to ensure a synchronous execution order, fetching from local cache first and making the API call only when necessary?

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```java
public class MetadataFetcher {

    public Mono<Map<String, Object>> enrichData(String id) {
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(localCache.getIfPresent(id))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> fetchFromCache(id, cacheService)))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> fetchFromApi(id, fallbackService)))
                .defaultIfEmpty(transformationUtil.defaultEmptyMap())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single());
    }

    private Mono<Map<String, Object>> fetchFromCache(String id, DataService dataService) {
        return dataService.getSymbolMetadata(id, new HashMap<>())
                .flatMap(symbolData -> {
                    if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(symbolData)) {
                        return Mono.empty();
                    } else {
                        localCache.put(id, symbolData);
                        return Mono.just(symbolData);
                    }
                });
    }

    private Mono<Map<String, Object>> fetchFromApi(String id, DataService dataService) {
        return dataService.getSymbolMetadata(id, new HashMap<>())
                .flatMap(symbolData -> {
                    if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(symbolData)) {
                        return Mono.empty();
                    } else {
                        localCache.put(id, symbolData);
                        return Mono.just(symbolData);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MetadataFetcher metadataFetcher = new MetadataFetcher(/* pass dependencies */);

        // Example caller
        String id = "exampleId";
      kafkaEventsFlux.
    .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
    .flatmap(data -> enrichData(data).subscribeOn(single))
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap` when you want to enforce *sequential* processing of the elements of a Flux.

Comment: could you please explain more about using concatMap? looks like it's working with concatMap.

does using subscribeOn(Schedulers.single()) with flatMap does not work? according to my understanding, this also subscribes to each event one after another. 
or subscribeOn does not affect the flatMap operator?

Comment: One of the key aspect of Reactor is to allow multiple concurrent tasks to be started and paused on the same thread. *flatMap* enforces concurrency whatever the scheduler, even if it uses only a single thread. *concatMap* forces signals to be processed one after another.